# ggalluvial (r package) example gives error

Tags: r, plot, graph-visualization

Am i missing something? the example in the ggalluvial package gives this error:

```
> library(ggalluvial)
> ggplot(as.data.frame(Titanic),
+        aes(weight = Freq,
+            axis1 = Class, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Age,
+            fill = Survived)) +
+   geom_alluvium() +
+   scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Class", "Sex", "Age"))
Error: Invalid column specification
```

UPDATE 2:
as per DanHall's request:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggalluvial_0.6.0 ggthemes_3.4.0   alluvial_0.1-2   dplyr_0.5.0      purrr_0.2.2      readr_0.2.2      tidyr_0.6.1     
 [8] tibble_1.3.4     ggplot2_2.2.1    tidyverse_1.1.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     compiler_3.4.3   plyr_1.8.4       base64enc_0.1-3  forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.3      digest_0.6.12   
 [8] evaluate_0.10.1  jsonlite_1.5     lubridate_1.5.6  gtable_0.2.0     nlme_3.1-128     lattice_0.20-33  rlang_0.1.4     
[15] psych_1.6.4      DBI_0.6          yaml_2.1.14      parallel_3.4.3   haven_1.0.0      stringr_1.2.0    httr_1.3.1      
[22] knitr_1.19       xml2_1.1.1       hms_0.3          rprojroot_1.2    grid_3.4.3       R6_2.2.2         readxl_0.1.1    
[29] rmarkdown_1.8    reshape2_1.4.2   modelr_0.1.0     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.1  htmltools_0.3.6  scales_0.5.0    
[36] rsconnect_0.8.5  assertthat_0.1   mnormt_1.5-4     rvest_0.3.2      colorspace_1.3-2 labeling_0.3     stringi_1.1.6   
[43] lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.1
```

Comment: what's the result of `traceback()` when the error is thrown?

Comment: And also, what happens when you run `example(geom_alluvium, package = "ggalluvial")`?

Comment: @DanHall: when I run the example() i get the same error as in my post.

Comment: What's the result of `sessionInfo()`? Edit your question with that in the body.

Comment: @DanHall: sessionInfo() up.

Comment: I can think of two possible problems here: 1. Some of your packages aren't up to date. Try running `update.packages()` and see what you can update, then try again.  2. Your search list is in an order that has conflicts. I don't think this is the issue, because I think I've made my search list look like yours and still don't see a problem.

Comment: @DanHall - If you add this bit to your answer I can check mark it as right; I had some out of date packages that were buggering thing up. ty.

Comment: done! glad i could help, and thank you for marking it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below, this code works on another machine. When something that is working for other people isn't working for you, it can be useful to run `update.packages()` and follow the instructions to update any outdated packages you may have installed. This turned out to be the solution here.

It works on my machine as is:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(Titanic),
      aes(weight = Freq, 
          axis1 = Class, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Age,
          fill = Survived)) +
  geom_alluvium() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Class", "Sex", "Age"))
```

[image]

It also works when calling `example(geom_alluvium, package = "ggalluvial")`.

Here's another usage example (from the vignette).

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(Titanic),
       aes(weight = Freq,
           axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class),
                width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class")) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Titanic survival by class and sex")
```